# Layered Navigation is not working on Searched Result Page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I have been assigned on a task in which layered navigation is working perfect on product list page while not working on Searched Result page.

Only one filter is working fine but not when we try to apply 2 filters with 'AND'

Any clue how to fix it.

Comment: two filter is display in search page?

Comment: yup two filters should by applied on search result. like Color:Black and Size:Large

Comment: @NaveedRamzan are you able to fix this?

Comment: @Deeps, no idea, coz I have been shifted to other project. Do you have some solution or you are also looking for solution ?

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Yes, I'm still looking for a solution. Btw, I'm using Mirasvit's Search extension too.